# Change an element when an event occurs

Tags: jquery

I want to change the element an event is attached to. In the below example I try to increase the border from 2px to 10 px without success.

Complete minimal example (look for the FAILS row):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>P { margin-bottom: 40%; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

$('p').each(function (i) {
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid');

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        console.log('scroll triggered, but nothing happens!');
        event.target.css('border', '10px solid'); // FAILS with TypeError: event.target.css is not a function
    });
})

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What border exactly you try to change? Of the whole window?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Each `p` from the `2px` I initially set using jQuery to `10px` when scroll occurs. Edit: I see my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You event.target is the window itself so you can't apply css to the p tags this way, although you can do this way : http://jsbin.com/abebof/1/edit

```
$('p',event.target).css('border', '10px solid');
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly select the element(s) which you want to apply the css to.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
        console.log('scroll triggered, but nothing happens!');
        $('body').css('border', '10px solid'); // FAILS with TypeError: event.target.css is not a function
    });
```

Even if you use `event.target`, you would have to wrap it in a jQuery collection before you could use the `.css` method:

```
$(event.target).css...
```

The problem with this is that applying css to the window doesn't work; you can only apply css to `HTMLElement` objects (which are found from the document down).